# kubectl exec with parameter -ti completion failed

Tags: kubectl, zsh-completion

Zsh completion works fine for `kubectl exec`, but failed for `kubectl exec -ti`.

I already did this `echo "[[ $commands[kubectl] ]] && source <(kubectl completion zsh)" >> ~/.zshrc # add autocomplete permanently to your zsh shell` from official document [Kubectl autocomplete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#zsh)

When I press tab key after input `kubectl exec`, pod names were list, but nothing return when I press tab after input `-ti` or `-it`. No error info in the command line.

Where can I find the completion log?
How to troubleshooting this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the commands and the error thrown.

Comment: @Srividya When I press `tab` key after input `kubectl exec`, pod names were list, but nothing return when I press `tab` after input `-ti`.  No error info in the command line.  Where can I find the error?

Comment: You are using command "kubectl exec -ti" but instead of that use "kubectl exec -it", or "kubectl exec -stdin". Refer [here](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#getting-a-shell-to-a-container) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compatible issue.

The server version is 1.16 and the client version of `kubectl` is 1.22, which is not supported perfectly to the server.

When I execute `kubectl version`, got the warning below:

`WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.16) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1`

So I downloaded a [specific version kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-macos) with `curl -LO " https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.16.6/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl"`. The completion works.